# jquery validation ... validate method not working but not throwing error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a popup notifyDa and also the popup displays 3 different conditions..
This is working fine.The problem i am facing is in validation.
validate method is not working.
And also apart from "required" field validation, I have a scenario where there are 2 dropdowns and if either one is selected,the form can be submitted..

My code for popup is

```
function notifyDa(daValueForUser) {
        var ctx = '${contextPath}';
        var queryUrl = ctx + "/excessList.htm?getDaList=true";

        var html = "<form id='notifyForm'><table><tr><td align='center' colspan='2'> Excess Notification </td></tr>";
        $.ajax({
            url : queryUrl,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "text",
            success : function(result) {
                result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);  // as dataType is Text
                var items = result;

    if(daValueForUser>=4) {
                    html = html + "<tr><td>Select DA Holder</td><td><select id='daList'><option>select</option>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"+items[i]+"</option>";
                    }
                }
    if (daValueForUser<=3) { 
                    html = html + "<tr><td>Select DA4 Holder</td><td><select id='daList1'>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"
                                + items[i] + "</option>";
                    }
                    html = html + "</select></td></tr><tr><td>Select DA4 Holder</td><td><select id='daList2'>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"
                                + items[i] + "</option>";
                    }
                }
                html = html+"</select></td></tr><tr><td>Comments:</td><td><input name='comments'></td></tr>" +  
                    "<tr><td></td><td> <table><tr><td align='right'><button type='button' onclick='javascript:sendNotifyDetails();'>Send</button></td><td align='left'><button type='button' onclick='javascript:closeNotifyDaPopup();'>Cancel</button></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></form>";

                $('#notifyDiv').empty();
                $('#notifyDiv').html(html);

                $("#pop").click(function() {
                    $("#notifyDiv").fadeIn(1000);
                    if (!$("#notifyDiv").is(':visible')) {
                        return;
                    }
                });

                $("#notifyDiv").css({
                    left : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 2,
                    top : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 7,
                    position : 'absolute'
                });

                $('#daList1').change(function(e) {
                    index = this.selectedIndex;
                    $('#daList2 option').prop('disabled', false); // enable all options
                    if (index != 0) {
                        $('#daList2').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; // so you don't disable the option after it's selected
                        $('#daList2 option:eq(' + index + ')').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            },
            error : function() {

            }
        });

    }
```

My code for validation is

```
    function sendNotifyDetails(){
        alert("Inside close");

        $("#notifyForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!");},
            rules: {
                daList: "required",
                comments: "required"
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            messages: {
                daList:  "Select a DA Holder",
                comments: "Enter comments"
            }
        });

}
```

---

It is entering validate method but not displaying error message.
I gave error element as span and also insert before option.
Now i changed the code to

```
function notifyDa(daValueForUser) {
        var ctx = '${contextPath}';
        var queryUrl = ctx + "/excessList.htm?getDaList=true";
        //daValueForUser=3
        var html = "<form id='notifyForm'><span class='errorMessage'></span><div id='error'></div><table><tr><td align='center' colspan='2'> Excess Notification </td></tr>";
        $.ajax({
            url : queryUrl,
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "text",
            success : function(result) {
                result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);  // as dataType is Text
                var items = result;

                if(daValueForUser>=4) {
                    html = html + "<tr><td>Select DA Holder</td><td><select id='daList'><option>select</option>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"+items[i]+"</option>";
                    }
                }
                if (daValueForUser<=3) { 
                    html = html + "<tr><td>Select DA4 Holder</td><td><select id='daList1'>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"
                                + items[i] + "</option>";
                    }
                    html = html + "</select></td></tr><tr><td>Select DA4 Holder</td><td><select id='daList2'>";
                    for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        html = html + "<option value='"+items[i]+"'>"
                                + items[i] + "</option>";
                    }
                }
                html = html+"</select></td></tr><tr><td>Comments:</td><td><input name='comments'></td></tr>" +  
                    "<tr><td></td><td> <table><tr><td align='right'><input type='submit' value='Send'/></td><td align='left'><button type='button' onclick='javascript:closeNotifyDaPopup();'>Cancel</button></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></form>";

                $('#notifyDiv').empty();
                $('#notifyDiv').html(html);

                $("#notifyForm").validate({
                    submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!");},
                    errorElement: "span",
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        error.insertBefore($("#error"));
                    },
                    rules: {
                        daList: "required",
                        comments: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        daList:  "Enter DA Holder",
                        comments: "comments required"
                    }
                });

                $("#notifyDiv").fadeIn(1000);



                $("#notifyDiv").css({
                    left : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 2,
                    top : ($(window).width() - $('#notifyDiv').width()) / 7,
                    position : 'absolute'
                });

                $('#daList1').change(function(e) {
                    index = this.selectedIndex;
                    $('#daList2 option').prop('disabled', false); // enable all options
                    if (index != 0) {
                        $('#daList2').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; // so you don't disable the option after it's selected
                        $('#daList2 option:eq(' + index + ')').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                }); 
            },
            error : function() {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `.validate()` is the plugin's _initialization_, not a method to test the form. `.validate()` should only be called immediately after the form is first constructed.  See Ryley's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `$('#notifyForm').validate` before the close event happens.

So as soon as you've created the form with this code:

```
$('#notifyDiv').html(html);
```

Right after that is where you should be calling validate:

```
    $("#notifyForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!");},
        rules: {
            daList: "required",
            comments: "required"
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        messages: {
            daList:  "Select a DA Holder",
            comments: "Enter comments"
        }
    });
```

Then, change your button to be a submit button like this:

Old:

```
<button type='button' onclick='javascript:sendNotifyDetails();'>Send</button>
```

New:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

This will automatically trigger validation and if the form is valid, your submitHandler will be called.

Comment: This is probably a different issue entirely, my solution seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/5jTSc/

Comment: I copied ur entire code and only ran that code...even then error message is not being displayed